# Need better way to maintain Fieldset width during slideToggle call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a good way to maintain the width of a fieldset element when I "collapse" the inner div using slideToggle.

**My CSS:**

```
.SlidePromptFldSet {
     background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0;    
}

.SlidePromptLgnd {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;    

    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
    <fieldset id="fldSet"  class="SlidePromptFldSet" style=" width:100%;" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
        <legend id="lgnd" style="width:100%" class="SlidePromptLgnd" onclick="SlidePrompt(this);"
                 runat="server" clientidmode="Static">                   
        </legend>

        <div id="bodyDiv" style=" width:100%; " class="SlidePromptBodyDiv" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">
             Lorem ipsum neque erat vestibulum primis dui velit venenatis 
             tellus, risus eu eget lorem litora habitasse integer consectetur, dictum proin 
             venenatis sociosqu lobortis mauris quis porttitor dolor tempus rutrum mauris 
             nullam congue eget fringilla convallis.

        </div>    
    </fieldset>
```

**My jQuery**

```
var prmptWdth;

function SlidePrompt(promptLegend) {
    if (typeof prmptWdth === "undefined") {
       prmptWdth = $(promptLegend).parent().css("width");
    }

   $(promptLegend).parent().css("width", prmptWdth);


    $(promptLegend).parent().find(".SlidePromptBodyDiv").slideToggle();

}
```

**Question:**

This works but I was hoping there was I graceful way to do it. My *SlidePrompt* function basically gets the fieldset's current width and re-assigns it to the fieldset. Is there a better way to do this using CSS, etc.?

Comment: You could try with a `min-width` on the parent... But your way looks like the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I thought of another approach involves putting a wrapper div arround my bodydiv. I have the details below.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. It might be real elaquent but it seems to cover the case where the window size gets changed. I put a wrapper div arround the *bodyDiv* of my fieldset. When the user clicks the legend, I set the height of wrapper to 1px. When the legend is clicked again, I set the height of the wrapper back to the height the height of*bodyDiv* .

**My jQuery:**

```
function SlidePrompt(promptLegend) {

if (!$(promptLegend).parent().find("#wrpper").hasClass("closed")) {
    $(promptLegend).parent().find("#wrpper").css("height", "1px");
    $(promptLegend).parent().find("#wrpper").addClass("closed");
}
else {
    $(promptLegend).parent().find("#wrpper").css("height",
                                                  $(promptLegend).parent().find(".SlidePromptBodyDiv").css("height"));
    $(promptLegend).parent().find("#wrpper").removeClass("closed");  
}
```